# Add attribute to wordpress menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using a lightweight lightbox script for my wordpress site.   I want one of the main navigation buttons to open a Vimeo link in the lightbox.    The documentation of the lightbox says to "Add the 'data-lity' attribute to any `<a>` elements for which you want the links to be opened in a lightbox"...like so:

```
<a href="//vimeo.com/1084537" data-lity>iFrame Vimeo</a>
```

That works fine for a normal on page links - but I don't see any way in wordpress menus to add that "data-lity" attribute to the wordpress menu.    How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

Add this code to your current theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpse44532_add_attr_menu_atts', 10, 3 );
function wpse44532_add_attr_menu_atts( $atts, $item, $args )
{
  // The id of the target menu item
  $menu_target = 44;
  if ($item->ID == $menu_target) {
    $atts['data-lity'] = 'test';
  }
  return $atts;
}
```

Comment: Yup - I just changed the 44 to my menu ID and BOOM it worked perfect!   Thank you.

Comment: i did immediately... but apparently I'm too "new" to be allowed the privilege to upvote. :(